# Manage exceptions with spring @ControllerAdvice thrown in a JSF controller

Tags: java, spring, exception, jsf, controller-advice

Is there a way to let my custom `ExceptionHandler` annoted with `@ControllerAdvice` manage exceptions thrown in a **JSF** controller?

I noticed that all exceptions thrown in `@PostConstruct` methods won't get caught by the `@ControllerAdvice` class, instead **JSF** built in exception handler manage them.

I'm aware that I can extend `ExceptionHandlerFactory`, but all the guides I found are outdated and it's not clear if I can use it for the functionality I need.

Comment: PostContruct methods triggered on app startup. Quite probably your ExceptionHandlers are not initialized by Spring. And why do you want to catch in handler start up annotations?

Comment: Spring `ExceptionHandler` will work for controllers/handlers executed in the context of a Spring `DispatcherServlet` this is not the case with JSF so this will not work, unless you place JSF behind the `DispatcherServlet`, but that would complicate things only.

Comment: @DanilaZharenkov **@ControllerAdvice** is working properly, for example if I try to go to a path that is not mapped in any controller, it catches the exception. Only if I'm in a JSF controller my ExceptionHandler won't get called.